# Create a post with REST API and adding a category

Tags: ajax, javascript, rest-api

I can successfully create posts, set titles, content and status with Javascript/Wordpress but I am having a hard time setting the category. What is the correct syntax for setting categories with Javascript and REST API?

HTML

```
<select id="post_category">
  <option value="123">Bulldogs</option>
  <option value="456">Poodles</option>
  <option value="789">Pitbulls</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-post-btn');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var postData = {
    "title": document.getElementById('post_title').value,
    "content": document.getElementById('post_content').value,
    "status": 'publish',
    "categories": [document.getElementById('post_category').value]
  }
};

var createPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
createPost.open("POST", "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts");
createPost.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", postToken.nonce);
createPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
createPost.send(JSON.stringify(postData));
createPost.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(createPost.readyState === 4){
        if(createPost.status === 200){
            console.log("Success");
        } else {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Install `Basic Auth` plugin on your site where you want to create a new post. URL: https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth. And pass the `header`. Check this gist for reference https://gist.github.com/maheshwaghmare/6817f61c08d6c4e560a25cccba57a292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple. Set DOM element value in JS variable instead of "document.getElementById('post_category').value" in array.

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-post-btn');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var categoryTerm = document.getElementById('post_category').value;
  var postData = {
  "title": document.getElementById('post_title').value,
  "content": document.getElementById('post_content').value,
  "status": 'publish',
  "categories": [categoryTerm]
  }
};
```